# SonarQube Build Breaker does not report failure

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I want to fail the build in Jenkins when the code is not passing the quality gate. But for some reason the Build breaker plugin does not report failure and I don't know understand why.

- SonarQube 4.4
- Build breaker v. 1.1

Output from Jenkins with project name and settings renamed.

```
20:01:07 + mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://something:5432/sonarqube -Dsonar.jdbc.username=something -Dsonar.jdbc.password=something -Dsonar.host.url=http://something -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-it.exec -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true -Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true -Dsonar.preview.includePlugins=buildbreaker -Dsonar.preview.excludePlugins=devcockpit,jira,pdfreport,views,report,buildstability,scmactivity
20:01:08 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
20:01:09 [INFO]                                                                         
20:01:09 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:01:09 [INFO] Building some-project
20:01:09 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:01:10 [INFO] 
20:01:10 [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) @ some-project ---
20:01:10 [INFO] SonarQube version: 4.4
20:01:11 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
20:01:11 INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some-project_review-1/workspace-34_2014-08-18_20-00-17/target/sonar
20:01:11 INFO: SonarQube Server 4.4
20:01:11 [INFO] [20:01:11.651] Preview mode
20:01:11 [INFO] [20:01:11.656] Load global settings
20:01:11 [INFO] [20:01:11.815] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
20:01:11 [INFO] [20:01:11.824] Install plugins
20:01:11 [INFO] [20:01:11.845] Include plugins: buildbreaker
20:01:11 [INFO] [20:01:11.845] Exclude plugins: devcockpit, jira, pdfreport, views, report, buildstability, scmactivity
20:01:12 [INFO] [20:01:12.019] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some-project_review-1/workspace-34_2014-08-18_20-00-17/target/sonar/.sonartmp/preview1408392071940-0
20:01:12 [INFO] [20:01:12.692] Initializing Hibernate
20:01:17 [INFO] [20:01:17.535] Loading technical debt model...
20:01:17 [INFO] [20:01:17.653] Loading technical debt model done: 118 ms
20:01:17 [INFO] [20:01:17.666] Load project settings
20:01:17 [INFO] [20:01:17.730] Apply project exclusions
20:01:18 [INFO] [20:01:18.081] -------------  Scan Something Project
20:01:18 [INFO] [20:01:18.086] Load module settings
20:01:19 [INFO] [20:01:19.327] Loading rules...
20:01:20 [INFO] [20:01:20.190] Loading rules done: 863 ms
20:01:20 [INFO] [20:01:20.233] Configure Maven plugins
20:01:20 [INFO] [20:01:20.415] Compare to previous analysis (2014-08-18)
20:01:20 [INFO] [20:01:20.438] Compare over 30 days (2014-07-19, analysis of 2014-08-18 17:26:53.918)
20:01:20 [INFO] [20:01:20.472] Loaded quality gate 'something'
20:01:20 [INFO] [20:01:20.680] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer...

[a lot of extra output excluded that I guess it not needed]

20:01:45 [INFO] [20:01:45.181] Export results to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some-project_review-1/workspace-34_2014-08-18_20-00-17/target/sonar/sonar-report.json
20:01:45 [INFO] [20:01:45.204] Store results in database
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.088] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.089] Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.601] HTML Issues Report generated: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some-project_review-1/workspace-34_2014-08-18_20-00-17/target/sonar/issues-report/issues-report.html
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.684] Light HTML Issues Report generated: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some-project_review-1/workspace-34_2014-08-18_20-00-17/target/sonar/issues-report/issues-report-light.html
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.690] 
20:01:46 
20:01:46 -------------  Issues Report  -------------
20:01:46 
20:01:46         +3 issues
20:01:46 
20:01:46         +3 major
20:01:46 
20:01:46 -------------------------------------------
20:01:46 
20:01:46 
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.690] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
20:01:46 [INFO] [20:01:46.703] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
20:01:46 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:01:46 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
20:01:46 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:01:46 [INFO] Total time: 38.148s
20:01:46 [INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 18 20:01:46 UTC 2014
20:01:47 [INFO] Final Memory: 35M/744M
20:01:47 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:01:47 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the sonarqube you need to associate project with your quality gate.

See 1. point in section USAGE

[SonarQube documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin)

In my case I on **dashboard** I clicked on project, in right upper corner click on **configuration** and Quality Gate.

It looks that default is empty and change it to SonarWay (or your own). Don't forget to hit **update** button

Comment: Hm.. Didn't work for me. My project is associated with a quality gate, but my build is still not failing, even though it's not passing the quality gate..

Comment: [INFO] [10:06:24.267] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
[WARN] [10:06:24.268] Coverage < 80
[WARN] [10:06:24.268] Critical issues > 0
[WARN] [10:06:24.268] Line coverage < 80
[WARN] [10:06:24.268] Package tangle index > 0
[INFO] [10:06:24.268] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mfss-user ......................................... SUCCESS [42.272s]

Comment: Oh, I got it! The problem was that those issues in quality gate were configured as warnings, but not as errors